# jquery remove contents of last td

Tags: jquery

I have a table $("#Customers").

```
<table id="Customers">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>
        <input id="model_0_name" type="text" name="model[0].name"/>              
    </td>
    <td>
        <button>Add</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Each row has a button in the last td element. I want to clone the row and add it below the row that was clicked. I want to remove the button element from the cloned row. The cloning part is working but the button is not being removed. Furthermore, I would like to rename the id and the name of the new input row to the new index: eg: model[1].name.

```
 $("#Customers > tbody > tr").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        // get row index
        var rowndx = $("tr").index(this);
        var cnt = $("#Customers > tbody > tr").length;
        var clonerow = $(this)
            .clone()
            .wrap("<tr></tr>").parent().html();
        $("#Customers > tbody > tr").eq(rowndx - 1).after(clonerow).remove("tr > td:last");          
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do like:

```
..
var clonerow = $(this)
            .clone().find("button").remove().end()
            .wrap("<tr></tr>").parent().html();
```

Demo:: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zbdtq/)

Working code:

```
$("#Customers > tbody > tr").click(function (event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   // get row index
   var rowndx = $("tr").index(this);
   var cnt = $("#Customers > tbody > tr").length;
   var clonerow = $(this)
            .clone().find("input").attr("id", "model_"+cnt+"_name").end().find("button").remove().end()
            .wrap("<tr></tr>").parent().html();
   $("#Customers > tbody > tr").eq(rowndx - 1).after(clonerow);          
});
```

Updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zbdtq/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You should try to remove from clone object:

```
var clonerow = $(this)
    .clone().find("td:last").remove().end()
    .wrap("<tr></tr>").parent().html();
```

[Here is working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Zbdtq/2/)

Answer (score 0):

i added the click event to add button.. since with selector as `<tr>` , focusing on input will end up adding new `<tr>`.

try this

```
$("#Customers > tbody > tr > td > button").click(function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  // get row index
  var $tr = $(this).parents('tr'); //get parent `tr`
  var countTR = $("#Customers tr").length //get total length of tr
  var cloned = $tr.clone(); //clone it
  cloned.find('td:last').remove(); //remove the last td from cloned element
  cloned.find('input').val('').attr('name', 'model' + [countTR + 1] + '.name') //find inout chnage name and empty the calue
  $("#Customers tr:last").after(cloned); //append it at the end
});
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/kcjF2/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$("#Customers > tbody > tr > td > button").on('click', function() {
    var $tr    = $(this).closest('tr');
    var $clone = $tr.clone();
    $clone.find('td:last').remove();
    $tr.after($clone);
});
```

[Fiddle Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/darhamid/dZ7Xm/)